# USB Mouse not working when connecting the power source

Tags: laptop, usb, mouse

Am using Sony Vio laptop. when connecting to the power source (AC Adapter) my USB mouse stops working. when disconnect the power source its working. Do i need to change any settings to work even my lap connected with power source??

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the power options are the same for when plugged in and battery. Try mouse. If it fails, look at device manager, find the mouse go to properties and make sure the pc does not disable it under power options.

Or you have a hardware/build fault and the by plugging in power in it 'shorting' (not correct use of word).